# RTT/TDD/TTY keyboard not showing in dialer app, for those of us with disabilities

Tags: lineageos, 9.0-pie, phone-app, accessibility

- There is an option to enable TTY in LineageOS 16, but it seems to do nothing. `Phone -> menu -> Settings -> Accessibility -> TTY Mode -> TTY Full`
- Full documentation of functionality for users: https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9042284?hl=en

  - This step never shows:

    4. While the phone rings, the other person's screen displays an RTT indicator Real-time text.
- Is this also supposed to enable TDD? Does the phone automatically detect TDD tones then fallback to TTY tones?

Edit:

- Here is a page showing the desired functionality, but on iOS 10. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207033

  - It looks like iOS also  has more options which I think would be very useful  in LineageOS/Android, for example placing the call directly or automatically dialing into a relay.

Comment: Looks like there's a prerequisite from the linked Google Support: "*To find out if you can use RTT with your device and service plan, check with your carrier.*". Perhaps that's what you need to confirm first?

Comment: I am unsure which carriers don't support it, but mine says they do. Mine is an MVNO that operates off of AT&T towers in the US. Good catch though. Edit: Quote from FCC https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/use-tty-devices-digital-wireless-phones: "Wireless service providers have upgraded their digital networks to be compatible with TTYs. Consumers are now generally able to use TTYs to complete calls with their digital wireless phones, including 911 calls, if the phone itself is TTY-compatible."